# ADODB::_RecordsetPtr::GetRecordCount() failure

Tags: c++, select, ado

I am trying to use ADO to do some queries in C++. Here is my code

```
string commandline = "SELECT * FROM My_Table";

ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS("ADODB.Recordset");

ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");

pRS->Open(commandline.c_str(), _variant_t((IDispatch *) pConn, true), ADODB::adOpenUnspecified,  ADODB::adLockUnspecified, ADODB::adCmdText);

cout<<pRS->GetRecordCount();
```

I have 1000 records in `My_Table`, thus I expect to see output `1000`. However, the output is `-1`.

May I know what am I wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `RecourdCount` property works only if the underlying provider or cursor type actually support it, otherwise -1 is returned.

Try using a static cursor (passing `ADODB::adOpenStatic` instead of `ADODB::adOpenUnspecified`)

Please also note that even when the provider supports it, getting the record count may use a lot of resources because the provider has to fetch all records prior to knowing the number of records affected by the query.

Refer to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page for detailed documentation.